# PHP array code to solve

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, joomla

I have component on joomla for video. I want get id and thumbnail of current item. I use code below and get id and thumnail from database.

```
/// **Get a db connection.**
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
 // **Create a new query object.**
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('id','thumbnail')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__hwdms_media'));

$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();//Load data from database
$thisitem = $this->item->id; // **HWD media share this item id** 
$objectoarr = json_decode(json_encode($results),true); // **Convert stdClass object to array**
```

When printing

```
print_r ($objectoarr);
```

get result

```
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46
            [thumbnail] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SXTOwG1XhSM/maxresdefault.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 47
            [thumbnail] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ASoOUK05d4A/maxresdefault.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 48
        [thumbnail] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/i4VkHHh0n7Q/sddefault.jpg
    )
```

After this point i have problem. 
I need take from array `id` and `thumbnail` of item. If `id` equal to `$thisitem = $this->item->id`

Show this item `thumbnail`.
Please help to resolve this.

Comment: Your result starts from index 18? Why?

Comment: Just all before this numbers thumbnails was empty. Now correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you simply have to loop through the Array that you receive and check if the id of the inner thumbnail array matches.

```
foreach ($objecttoarr as $thumbnail) {
    if ($thumbnail['id'] == $this->item->id) {
        // Do something with $thumbnail['id'] and $thumbnail['thumbnail']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a small adjustment to the code fetching data, and you will get id as keys in the array:

```
$results = $db->loadObjectList('id');//Load data from database
```

Now you can get by id:

```
$current = $results[$this->item->id]; // this is you current item
```

[Docs for JDatabaseDriver->loadObjectList()](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseDriver.html#method_loadObjectList)